# Java websocket server giving 404

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I'm trying to build a java websocket server. I've written a simple server endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test")
public class EndPoint {
    static Queue<Session> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Session>();

    public static void send(int a, int b) {
        try {
            for(Session session : queue) {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("a = " + a + ",b=" + b);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void openConnection(Session session) {
        queue.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void closeConnection(Session session) {
        queue.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
        queue.remove(session);
    }
}
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


</web-app>
```

When I hit ws://localhost:8080/websocket-1.0/test from Javascript, I get a 404 response. I'm using tomcat 8 to deploy this. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using the websocket.ExampleConfig class from examples webapp of Tomcat ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Use latest version of Tomcat 7.0.x or latest version of Tomcat 8.0.x

2) Make sure your war contains only the ServerEndpoint classes and an empty web.xml. Tomcat automatically scans and loads the classes annotated with ServerEndpoint annotation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

</web-app>
```

3) Verify that catalina.out has the following log msg and there are no exceptions.

org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/webapps/.war

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.4/index/websocket-api.html and my expereince the endpoint should match the ws: url

E.g.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test")
ws://localhost:8080/test
```

or

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket-1.0//test")
ws://localhost:8080/websocket-1.0/test
```

Comment: I'm still getting 404. Am I missing anything in web.xml?

Comment: are you sure you are on port 8080?

Comment: Can the port be changed via the annotation?